# ScrollView hides the title bar

Tags: java, android

My small app was working well. When I used ScrollView it overrides the title bar of my App which is JustJava.

content.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
        android:text="Toppings"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Whipped Cream"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decrease"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="decrement"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/increase"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="increment"

            android:text="+" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:text="Order summary"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:text="$0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"
        android:text="Order" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bablu.justjava;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.NumberFormat;


/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int quantity = 0;
    int pricePerCoffee = 5;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the plus button is clicked.
     */
    public void increment(View view) {
        quantity = quantity + 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the minus button is clicked.
     */
    public void decrement(View view) {
        if (quantity > 0) {
            quantity = quantity - 1;
        }
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        CheckBox whippedCreamCheckbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
        boolean hasChecked = whippedCreamCheckbox.isChecked();

        String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(hasChecked);
        displayMessage(priceMessage);

    }

    private int CalculatePrice(int numberOfCoffees) {
        int price = numberOfCoffees * pricePerCoffee;
        return price;
    }

    private String createOrderSummary(boolean hasChecked) {
        int getPrice = CalculatePrice(quantity);
        String priceMessage = "Name: Bablu Kumar" +
                "\nAdd whipped cream? " + hasChecked +
                "\nQuantity: " + quantity + "\n" + "Total: $" + getPrice;
        priceMessage = priceMessage + "\nThank you!";
        return priceMessage;
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void displayQuantity(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen
     */


    private void displayMessage(String message) {
        TextView OrderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
        OrderSummaryTextView.setText(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.bablu.justjava/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.bablu.justjava/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bablu.justjava">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.bablu.justjava.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is the picture.
[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKGcL.png)

Please help provide a solution to resolve the problem.

Comment: put your activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried like this :

```
<ScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
```

Or add `android:layout_below="+@id/toolbar"` or like  `android:layout_below="+@id/appbarlayout"`

Comment: Yes, I just tried your solutions but nothing happened.

Comment: also i need your activity_main.xml canyou post it ?

Comment: can you try to add  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to your appbar and toolbar ?

Comment: i can think about possibilities. I have a layout like you and working good. Did you tried NestedScrollView and add it app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" attribute

Comment: Wrap the scrollview in other layout may resolve this problem.